# Dividing two unsigned bytes Assembly

Tags: assembly

I'm having difficulty understanding just when and why to use `cbw/cwd/cdq/cqo`. I have two unsigned bytes `bNum1` and `bNum2` that I need to divide and store in a byte sized var `bAns`. I realize I need to place the data in AX but am unsure of how to place a byte inside of AX without getting the invalid size error:

```
mov ax, byte[bNum1]  # invalid size error
div byte[bNum2]
mov byte[bAns], al
```

how would I fix this error? I apologize for my rudimentary understanding in Assembly

Comment: Presumably, you're talking about [tag:x86] assembly? There's more than one type of processor in the world (e.g. [tag:arm]) and their assembly languages are different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cbw/cwd/cdq` instructions are used to sign extend numbers. So they are only useful for signed values, and only if the value is already in a register.

Given that `bnum1` is an unsigned byte in memory, you can load it and zero extend it with the `movzx` instruction, e.g.

```
movzx ax, byte[bNum1]
```